# Can I make the Gmail browser UI put the reply input box at the top?

Tags: gmail

In Gmail, when I get a response, it is at the top of the screen and the previous messages are listed underneath going down the screen.

However, when I reply, the box to type my message in is placed at the bottom of the screen, so I have to keep scrolling for miles to remind myself of what I'm replying to.

Can I get the message-entry box put at the top?

I've turned the conversations view off (not sure if that matters for this question).

So what's happening is that the reply box is under the message, which is really long since it includes the indented message train produced by other people's email apps (Outlook usually).

Is it possible to have Gmail put the reply box at the very top, above the message?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what you're describing is the default behavior. Are you using any Labs or perhaps third-party add-ons?

Answer (score 4):

When you are typing in your draft reply window, you'll see three dots ... at the lower right. Just click on them and the full thread will be displayed in the draft window. No need to scroll way up and then back down.

Comment: Thanks. For me the three dots are horizontal and lower left. There are other vertical dots lower right, however these popup a menu of options.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure I understand your question, but if you have conversations view on, if you want to reply to a message in a conversation, the box will open right below the respective message, even if there are other after it.

Comment: Okay. Interesting, it doesn't for me. I'll post a screenshot when I'm next at my desk.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, if you use Chrome. I developed it to solve the exact same problem. This puts reply box at the top of the page and sorts messages in the conversation to show latest at the top.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-reply-at-the-top/okmcmppcoeknickodfpmlancikgghcll

Leave feedback if you notice any issues.